# session_start cause 503 error with php7.0-fpm

Tags: php, ajax, prototypejs, http-status-code-503, fpm

I have olds applications (PHP 5.3, Apache 2.2) that I must migrate to `PHP7.0-FPM` and `Apache 2.4` (with Docker).

All applications seem to work except one. This application use `Prototype 1.6.0.3` and when `Ajax.Request` is called, a `503 error` is displayed (after the line `this.transport.send(this.body);`).

I really don't understand...

Here is PHP-FPM logs :

> [29-Dec-2017 09:34:24] WARNING: [pool www] child 848 exited on signal
>   11 (SIGSEGV) after 372.307974 seconds from start [29-Dec-2017
>   09:34:24] NOTICE: [pool www] child 858 started

Here is Apache logs :

> [Fri Dec 29 09:34:24.865850 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 429:tid
>   139741154125568] [client 192.168.99.1:64899] AH01067: Failed to read
>   FastCGI header, referer:
>   http://test.doc/test/rubriques.php?logindata=4672d5ddafae848456b93bcb02da4df1
>   [Fri Dec 29 09:34:24.867796 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 429:tid
>   139741154125568] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client
>   192.168.99.1:64899] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: http://test.doc/test/rubriques.php?logindata=4672d5ddafae848456b93bcb02da4df1

EDIT : I have the same `rewrite rules` as the production server.

In the JS file who calls `Ajax.Request`, the URL of request is `/appli/myappli/ctrl/mymodule/IndexCtrl.php` but, on the file system, the file is `IndexCtrl.class.php`, not `IndexCtrl.php`.
I remember I set my `ProxyPassMatch` like this : `ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/intranet"`
I think there is a mistake on my config, but I don't know where.

EDIT : I think session_start cause this error. Any idea?

Comment: It's OK !
The problem was due to a not set session variable and a @ prefix hiding the error... It's very ugly !
I saw this error thanks to `session_error_handler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK ! The problem was due to a not set session variable and a @ prefix hiding the error... It's very ugly ! I saw this error thanks to `session_error_handler`

Comment: I have this problem today. What is `session_error_handler`?